# Routing help - can ping device to router, but not device to router to device

Tags: route

for some reasons I don't want to go into (there is only one kind of router that can transmitt data throught that long internet cable)

I have to have 2 NATS here is a picture of my network diagram
[image]

I would like to ping the device on 192.168.89.240 from 192.168.1.4
I added the route to my 192.168.1.1 router: `/ip route add dst-address=192.168.89.0/24 gateway=192.168.1.2` (no the router is not mikrotik, I am just using mikrotik syntax to describe what I did, 192.168.1.2 is the adress that 192.168.1.1 assigned to the router2)

and now I can ping 192.168.89.1 from my 192.168.1.4 but still cannot ping 192.168.89.240
not sure why, do I need another route maybe, what is it and where do I add it (to 192.168.1.1 or to 192.168.89.1?)

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: Generally, you don't NAT inside your own LAN. Please add the router models and their configs to your question, using the editor's `{}` preformat option. Note that home networking and consumer-grade hardware are explicitly off topic here. For a device to be on topic here, the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support.

Comment: This is not home networking, this is a route question, its just that IPs are home format

I know I should not NAT inside my network, but right now this is the easiest option (easier to add a route, then to reconfigure the whole router)

sadly I cannot post config because its some proprietary router

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off NAT on the secondary router. You generally *don't NAT within your own LAN*. Also, the primary router needs a static route to the 192.168.89.0/24 network via 192.168.1.2.

Additionally, the primary router may need specific configuration to allow hairpin routing - many routers by default have deactivated routing a packet back out of the same interface it was received on.

Comment: OK, if I understand you corecly 
the primary router needs a static route to the 192.168.89.0/24(?) network via 192.168.1.2

this should already take care of that routing: /ip route add dst-address=192.168.89.0/24 gateway=192.168.1.2

so I need to allow hairpin on 192.168.89.1 router?

I am realy confused why am I able to acsess 192.168.89.1 router fine after adding my route, but cannot acsess the 192.168.89.240 device (located on that 192.168.89.1 router)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had firewall enabled on 192.168.89.1 router, so thats why I couldn't ping any inside devices

This was all you needed to make it work: `/ip route add dst-address=192.168.89.0/24 gateway=192.168.1.2`